# Summation of all possible cases of selection of Elements

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, subset, subset-sum

Suppose you are given an array of n elements each having a specific value

now we need to find
the sum of 
all those cases 
where

the elements are selected according to indexes 
and their values get multiplied.

To clarify ,  this is nothing but problem of finding all subsets of given number of elements

All i need to know that is there a method to find the solution in less than O(2^n) 
which is the only challenge 
The lower in complexity the better it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this product:

```
(1+a)*(1+b)*(1+c)*(1+d)*...
```

In its expansion, for every subset of {a,b,c,d,...} there is a term which is the product of that subset. This includes the empty subset, whose product is 1.

Comment: I think you are right , these a , b , c will be our array elements . Yep Absolutely. Thanks Wumpus Q Wumbley